# Uninstall a distutils installed project on windows?

Tags: python, pip, package, python-module, pywin32

I need to uninstall my `pywin32` package on windows and reinstall a different version. When I try using `pip uninstall pywin32` I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izsz2.png) error message saying "It is a distutils installed project". I assume this is because it was originally installed by an installation program, and not pip. However, the installer did not come with an 'uninstall' option. I've also tried `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir pywin32‑227‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl` to try and overwrite with the new package, but I get the [same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVTSR.png). Also, because I'm on windows I can't use `sudo apt-get` or something. Obviously I've also tried manually deleting the installation folder but may have missed some files? Any ideas how I can uninstall this and install my new package? I can figure out a way to post the original installation executable I used if needed.

On a related note, this is to solve a [larger issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziBor.png) that prompted me to install `pywin32` in the first place. Once I installed through an installer called `pywin32-219.win32-py2.7` I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT1L1.png) error message. Am I on the right track to fixing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that anything installed using an installer executable is officially stored as a program, even if it was a single python package. In this case the originally installed `pywin32-219` package could be uninstalled by the system through Control Panel -> Uninstall a Program. Then the new package could be installed using `pip` and the problem was fixed.